# syntax error in inner join query of four table

Tags: c#

```
 con = new OleDbConnection(cs.ConDB);
 con.Open();
 cmd =new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Task_ID)AS [Task ID],
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Complaint_ID) AS [Complaint ID],
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Cust_ID) AS [Customer ID], 
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Emp_ID) AS [Employee ID], 
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Assign_Date) AS [Assign Date], 
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Deadline) AS [Dead Line],
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Task_Status) AS [Task Status], 
           RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Status_Date) AS [Status check Date],
           RTRIM(EMP_DETAILS.Name) AS [Employee Name],
           RTRIM(CUST_DETAILS.Name) AS [CustomerName], 
           RTRIM(CUST_DETAILS.Mobile_no) AS [Customer's Mob], 
           RTRIM(COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_Type) AS [Complaint Type],
           RTRIM(COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_Description) AS [Complaint Description] 
  FROM TASK_ASSIGNMENT 
  INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Emp_ID = EMP_DETAILS.Emp_ID 
  INNER JOIN CUST_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Cust_ID = CUST_DETAILS.Cust_ID
  INNER JOIN COMPLAINT_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Complaint_ID = COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_ID", con);

//new OleDbCommand("SELECT RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Task_ID) AS [Task ID],RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Complaint_ID) AS [Complaint ID],RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Cust_ID) AS [Customer ID], RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Emp_ID) AS [Employee ID], RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Assign_Date) AS [Assign Date], RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Deadline) AS [Dead Line],RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Task_Status) AS [Task Status], RTRIM(TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Status_Date) AS [Status check Date],RTRIM(EMP_DETAILS.Name) AS [Employee Name],RTRIM(CUST_DETAILS.Name) AS [Customer Name], RTRIM(CUST_DETAILS.Mobile_no) AS [Customer's Mob], RTRIM(COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_Type) AS [Complaint Type],RTRIM(COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_Description) AS [Complaint Description] FROM TASK_ASSIGNMENT INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Emp_ID = EMP_DETAILS.Emp_ID INNER JOIN CUST_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Cust_ID = CUST_DETAILS.Cust_ID INNER JOIN COMPLAINT_DETAILS ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Complaint_ID = COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_ID", con);

OleDbDataAdapter myDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "EMP_Details");
myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Complaint_Details");
myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Task_Assignment");
myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Cust_Details");
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["EMP_details"].DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Task_Assignment"].DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Cust_Details"].DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Complaint_Details"].DefaultView;
con.Close();
```

Comment: is the syntax error in the query itself, or the code around it? If it is in the query, why don't you edit this and post only the query.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  What database is this, and what is the error exactly?  If you run the query through a SQL client what do you get?  This probably has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: I highly suggest porting that Sql Code over to Sql Server and creating a StoredProc. this is messy at best amd very difficult to read..

Comment: Is the database behind the OleDb an MS-Access db?

Comment: google works wonders if used properly [SqlDataAdapter Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)

Comment: Syntax error (Oprator missing) in query expression

Comment: then fix the query it's telling you what you need to do.. have you run the query in the access query builder..?

Comment: yes  i run it in  access query builder

Answer (score 2):

Add appropriate open/close parenthesis to isolate the different parts of the join (this seems to be a quirk required by MS-Access)

```
cmd =new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT ......
         ....
FROM ((TASK_ASSIGNMENT INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS 
       ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Emp_ID = EMP_DETAILS.Emp_ID) 
       INNER JOIN CUST_DETAILS 
       ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Cust_ID = CUST_DETAILS.Cust_ID) 
       INNER JOIN COMPLAINT_DETAILS 
       ON TASK_ASSIGNMENT.Complaint_ID = COMPLAINT_DETAILS.Complaint_ID
```

However, keep in mind that this query returns just one table, your attempt to call 4 time the Fill method doesn't produce 4 different tables

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an @ between the open parentheses and the opening double quote for the query, like this:

```
cmd =new OleDbCommand(@"SELEC..
```

Comment: It is an error introduced by the last edit. Originally the query was on a single line

Comment: @kashifkashi for someone whoms aspires to be a programmer, you are not doing yourself any justice by just stating `it's not working` show some more effort and do a google search and or look for some working examples.. your error(s) are obvious and I have posted a link to a site that will display at it's simplest form how to utilize SqlDataAdapter